# Scala 2.10 reflection, how do I extract the field values from a case class, i.e. field list from case class

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10, case-class

How can I extract the field values from a case class in scala using the new reflection model in scala 2.10?
For example, using the below doesn't pull out the field methods

```
  def getMethods[T:TypeTag](t:T) =  typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m:MethodSymbol => m
  }
```

I plan to pump them into

```
  for {field <- fields} {
    currentMirror.reflect(caseClass).reflectField(field).get
  }
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`MethodSymbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$MethodSymbol) has an `isCaseAccessor` method that allows you to do precisely this:

```
def getMethods[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
}.toList
```

Now you can write the following:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> getMethods[Person]
res1: List[reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol] = List(value age, value name)
```

And you get only the method symbols you want.

If you just want the actual field name (not the `value` prefix) and you want them in the same order then:

```
def getMethods[T: TypeTag]: List[String] =
  typeOf[T].members.sorted.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.name.toString
  }
```

Comment: Ah I realise now that my approach was wrong.  Any idea how to get the caseAccessors from an unknown case class? IE one which is currently stored in as val SomeCaseClass:Any

Comment: Wait, no got it
currentMirror.reflect(someCaseClass).symbol.asType.typeSignature.members

Comment: Can this work with multi-thread environment under scala 2.10 ?

Comment: Any way to make this return the methods in the same order they where declared??

Comment: @samthebest: Yes! Just add `.sorted` after `members` (see [the `MemberScope` docs for details](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Scopes$MemberScope)).

Comment: This would be handy to be directly part of `case class`es

Comment: I can't get this to compile due to `Symbols` is a `Trait` so its components - specifially `MethodSymbol` - can not be imported.  Can you expand the example to include the imports of `Symbols` and `MethodSymbol` ?

Comment: @javadba This is a six year old answer and I'm not terribly interested in updating it myself, but feel free to edit—it probably just needs a `scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
` import.

Comment: I asked the pros and cos of this approach vs shapeless approach, hopefully somebody can guide me a bit; https://stackoverflow.com/a/67532977/4582240; the only thing i noticed difference is this reflect approach requires the case class to be at the top level.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get fancier you can get them in order by inspecting the constructor symbol.  This code works even if the case class type in question has multiple constructors defined.

```
  import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  /**
    * Returns a map from formal parameter names to types, containing one
    * mapping for each constructor argument.  The resulting map (a ListMap)
    * preserves the order of the primary constructor's parameter list.
    */
  def caseClassParamsOf[T: TypeTag]: ListMap[String, Type] = {
    val tpe = typeOf[T]
    val constructorSymbol = tpe.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)
    val defaultConstructor =
      if (constructorSymbol.isMethod) constructorSymbol.asMethod
      else {
        val ctors = constructorSymbol.asTerm.alternatives
        ctors.map(_.asMethod).find(_.isPrimaryConstructor).get
      }

    ListMap[String, Type]() ++ defaultConstructor.paramLists.reduceLeft(_ ++ _).map {
      sym => sym.name.toString -> tpe.member(sym.name).asMethod.returnType
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm finding cases where this fails with `scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term` in the expression `constructorSymbol.asTerm.alternatives`. The documentation comment for `declaration` refers to `OverloadedSymbol`, but no such entity seems to exist.

Comment: It turns out that that was happening 'cause I was calling it with `this.type` from a trait used as a supertype of the case class in question.

Comment: Also, `case class P(i: Int)(j: Int)`.