# How to get list of fields and subfields of a Scala case class

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class

I have a nested data structure in case classes, like

**Update2** All vals are optional

```
case class A(b:Option[B] = None,c:Option[C] = None,d:Option[D] = None)
case class B(id:Option[String] = None, name:Option[String] = None)
case class C(cNode:Option[String] = None, cuser:Option[String] = None)
case class D(dData:Option[String] = None, dField:Option[String] = None)
```

I'm looking for a regex to track all fields from the Class A, through all of it's subclasses.

The code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190112/1791289) answer solve the first step of my problem. It list all of the fields of the first level (class A). I tried to change it to recursive call the same method but I can't get the TypeTag information of a MethodSymbol.

The result I'm expecting for this is a method that receives A as argument, and returns

> (b.id, b.name,c.cNode, c.cUser,d.dData, d.dFile)

How can I get the subfields attribute names from a case class?

**UPDATE**

I'm using scala 2.11

I also want it to be generated by reflection/macros because the data structure is complex and I want it to be updated when the case class are updated.

Comment: You can probably do it quite easily with macros, eg using shapeless `LabelledGeneric`

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet can you provide a link or an example?

Comment: Do you know that technically, an `Option` is another nested structure, with a field `x` in `Some`? Any recursive solution might make this appear in the result...

Comment: I was indeed able to derive an answer with shapeless (before the second update), using `LabelledTypeClassCompanion`, but it is not very easy to understand, and I'm not so sure it would be helpful.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I'm not yet confortable with scala reflection and macros, This is the second time that I need to use it and I couldn't figure this out by the docs. Is your answer based on macros? I think that if you post, and it work without the option, we can figure out how to the the type arg of the option by reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `methodSymbol.returnType`. It will give you the return type of the case accessor on which you can then recursively collect all its case accessors.

Here is a full example (assuming that every field is an `Option`):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class A(b:Option[B] = None,c:Option[C] = None,d:Option[D] = None)
case class B(id:Option[String] = None, name:Option[String] = None)
case class C(cNode:Option[String] = None, cuser:Option[String] = None)
case class D(dData:Option[String] = None, dField:Option[String] = None)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def allFields[T: TypeTag]: List[String] = {
  def rec(tpe: Type): List[List[Name]] = { 
    val collected = tpe.members.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
    }.toList
    if (collected.nonEmpty)
      collected.flatMap(m => rec(m.returnType.typeArgs.head).map(m.name :: _))
    else
      List(Nil)
  }
  rec(typeOf[T]).map(_.mkString("."))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> allFields[A]
res0: List[String] = List(d.dField, d.dData, c.cuser, c.cNode, b.name, b.id)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer this didn't work because the vals are option, and the return type return the option methods, I'll update the question

Comment: If you want to special case Options you'll have to get to the type argument of `Option` first, with `.typeArgs`.

Comment: Can you provide an example with typeArgs?

Answer (score 0):

**Important note**

This answer is not a good one in my opinion (I posted it on OP's request). It involves complicated structures from `shapeless` library to avoid dealing with macros or reflection (actually, it uses macros under the hood, but `shapeless` allows to forget about them).

---

This is based on `shapeless` `Generic` macros. It involves creating a typeclass for your data type, and infering the instances of this typeclass for any type which has a `LabelledGeneric` in shapeless, ie a data structure with `sealed trait`s and `case class`es:

```
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct, HList, HNil, LabelledTypeClass, LabelledTypeClassCompanion}

trait RecursiveFields[T] {
  def fields: List[List[String]]
  override def toString = fields.map(_.mkString(".")).mkString("(", ", ", ")")
}

object RecursiveFields extends LabelledTypeClassCompanion[RecursiveFields] {
  def apply[T](f: List[List[String]]): RecursiveFields[T] = new RecursiveFields[T] {
    val fields = f
  }

  implicit val string: RecursiveFields[String] = apply[String](Nil)
  implicit def anyVal[T <: AnyVal]: RecursiveFields[T] = apply[T](Nil)

  object typeClass extends LabelledTypeClass[RecursiveFields] {
    override def product[H, T <: HList](name: String, ch: RecursiveFields[H], ct: RecursiveFields[T]): RecursiveFields[shapeless.::[H, T]] =
      RecursiveFields{
        val hFields = if (ch.fields.isEmpty) List(List(name)) else ch.fields.map(name :: _)
        hFields ++ ct.fields
      }

    override def emptyProduct: RecursiveFields[HNil] = RecursiveFields(Nil)

    override def project[F, G](instance: => RecursiveFields[G], to: (F) => G, from: (G) => F): RecursiveFields[F] =
      RecursiveFields(instance.fields)

    override def coproduct[L, R <: Coproduct](name: String, cl: => RecursiveFields[L], cr: => RecursiveFields[R]): RecursiveFields[:+:[L, R]] =
      RecursiveFields[L :+: R](product(name, cl, emptyProduct).fields)

    override def emptyCoproduct: RecursiveFields[CNil] = RecursiveFields(Nil)
  }
}
```

Note that the coproduct part is not necessary while you only deal with `case class`es, (you may replace `LabelledTypeClass` with `LabelledProductTypeClass`, and the same for `Companion`). However, since `Option` is a coproduct, this is not true in our case, but it is unclear what choice we should make in that case (I chose to take the first possible choice in the coproduct, but this is not satisfactory).

To use this, just call `implicitly[RecursiveFields[A]].fields` to get a list whose elements are the desired fields (splitted on `.`, so that `b.name` is actually kept as `List(b, name)`).

Comment: Yeah, this seems a little complicated ;) But it's nice to get different ways of doing things. I couldn't call implicitly[RecursiveFields[A]].fields due to error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: RecursiveFields[A]