# Convert case class constructor parameters to String Array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have a case class as follows:
    `case class MHealthUser(acc_Chest_X: Double, acc_Chest_Y: Double, acc_Chest_Z: Double, activityLabel: Int)`

These form the schema of a Spark DataFrame, which is why I'm using a case class. I simply want to map these to an `Array[String]` so I can use the `ParamValidators.inArray(attributes)` method in Spark. I use the following code to map the constructor parameters to an array using reflection:

```
val attributes: Array[String] = MHealthUser.getClass.getConstructors.map(a => a.toString)
```

but this simply gives me an array of length 1 whereas I want an array of length 4, with the contents of the array being the dataset schema which I've defined, as a string. Otherwise I'm using the hard-coded values of the dataset schema, which is obviously inelegant.
In other words I want the output:

```
val attributes: Array[String] = Array("acc_Chest_X", "acc_Chest_Y", "acc_Chest_Z", "activityLabel")
```

I've been playing with this for a while and can't get it to work. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `ScalaReflection`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

ScalaReflection.schemaFor[MHealthUser].dataType match {
  case s: StructType => s.fieldNames
  case _ => Array[String]()
}
```

Outside Spark see [Scala. Get field names list from case class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31189754/8371915)

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 3, meta programming constructs provides us with a more Scala idiomatic solution:

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror
import scala.compiletime.constValueTuple
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
val userMirror = summon[Mirror.Of[User]]
constValueTuple[userMirror.MirroredElemLabels].toList.asInstanceOf[List[String]].toArray
```