# Change schema of Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame[SimpleType]`. SimpleType is a class that contains 16 fields. But I have to change it into `DataFrame[ComplexType]`.

I've got only schema of ComplexType(there is more than 400 fields), there is no case class for this type. I know mapping neccesary fields (but I don't know how to map it from `DataFrame[SimpleType] -> DataFrame[ComplexType]`), the rest fields I want to leave as nulls. Does anyone know how to do this in most efficent way?

Thanks

## edit

```
class SimpleType{
field1
field2
field3
field4
.
.
.
field16
}
```

I have got DataFrame that contains this simple type. Also I have a schema of complex type.
I want to convert this `DataFrame[SimpleType] -> Dataframe[ComplexType]`

Comment: posting your input and expected output would help.

Comment: @philantrovert done, edited the post

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
// function to get field names
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


def classAccessors[T: TypeTag]: List[String] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m}
.toList.map(s => s.name.toString)

val typeComplexFields = classAccessors[ComplexType]
val newDataFrame = simpleDF
                   .select(typeComplexFields
                            .map(c => if (simpleDF.columns.contains(c)) col(c) else lit(null).as(c)) : _*)
.as[ComplexType]
```

Credits also for author of [Scala. Get field names list from case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189754/scala-get-field-names-list-from-case-class), I've copied his function to get field names with modifications

Comment: @Tomasz I've undeleted my answer, please check it again if it was not working previously :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Right, I dont have case class od ComplexType, since it have more than 400 hundreds fields. I've got only schema for that ComplexType, and the fields names are different.