# Scala: How to get attribute names of a case class

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I have a case class  "Lr". I need to print all the attribute names as header delimited by tab like:

```
some1_ID    some2_ID
```

But I am getting ans:

```
value some1_ID  value some2_ID
```

May I get help on how to modify my code to get the right ans?

```
package com.......

case class Lr (
  some1_ID : Option[String],
  some2_ID : Option[String]
)

object EchoLr {

  def classAccessors[T: TypeTag]: String = typeOf[T].members.collect { 
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
  }.mkString("\t")

  def main( args:Array[String] ):Unit = {
    val testLR = Lr(Option("something1"),Option("something2"))
    println(classAccessors[Lr])
  }
}
```

I was following :

[Get field names list from case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189754/get-field-names-list-from-case-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
```

by

```
case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.name
```