# How to get map of field names to field types of case class with shapeless

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I browsed pretty much all tutorials and have "The Type Astronauts" on my desk but I still can't figure out how to write snippet which can extract map of names to types using shapeless from case class. To be precise I'm after following interface:

```
case class Sample(id: String, date: LocalDate)

def sampleExpectedMetadata = expectedMetadata[Sample] // = ("id" -> "String", "date" -> "LocalDate")

def expectedMetadata[T]: Map[String, String] = ???
```

Help from anyone who can assist with writing correct implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.record._
import shapeless.labelled._

object expectedMetadata {
  def apply[T](implicit g: GetFieldTypes[T]): Map[String, String] = g.getFieldTypes

  sealed trait GetFieldTypes[T] {
    def getFieldTypes: Map[String,String]
  }

  implicit val hnil = new GetFieldTypes[HNil] {
    def getFieldTypes = Map.empty
  }

  implicit def hcons[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
    wit: Witness.Aux[K],
    typ: Typeable[V],
    rest: GetFieldTypes[T]
  ) = new GetFieldTypes[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def getFieldTypes = rest.getFieldTypes + (wit.value.name -> typ.describe)
  }

  implicit def caseClass[T, G](implicit
    lg: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, G],
    rest: GetFieldTypes[G]
  ) = new GetFieldTypes[T] {
    def getFieldTypes = rest.getFieldTypes
  }
}
```

Sample use:

```
scala> case class Sample(id: String, date: LocalDate)
scala> expectedMetadata[Sample]
res1: Map[String,String] = Map(date -> LocalDate, id -> String)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong that Shapeless would have nothing to do with this sort of introspection, using the answer from [Get field names list from case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189754/get-field-names-list-from-case-class) and refining it, your answer would be:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def expectedMetadata[T](implicit t:TypeTag[T]):Map[String, String] = 
   t.tpe.members
    .collect { case m:MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m }
    .map(x => x.name.toString -> x.returnType.toString)
    .toMap
```

Where, `expectedMetadata[Sample]` will return `Map[String,String] = Map(date -> java.time.LocalDate, id -> String)`