# Spark DataFrame casting to Dataset Doesn't Update NullType Columns in Schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am creating a dataframe that gets initialized with some columns set to null. Before writing out, I typed the dataframe as a case class A. Given that we have a Dataset[A], i assumed that the underlying schema of the dataset would have the correct types; however, the schema is left as NullType. The following is an example of how to reproduce:

```
case class ExampleInput(
  name: String,
  age: Integer
)

case class ExampleOutput(
  name: String,
  age: Integer,
  filledLater: String
)

// Define Input
val inputDS: Dataset[ExampleInput] = Seq(ExampleInput("asdf", 1)).toDS

// Calculate Output
val outputDS: Dataset[ExampleOutput] = inputDS
  .withColumn("filledLater", lit(null))
  .as[ExampleOutput]
```

Expected Result Schema:

```
StructType(
  StructField("name", StringType, true),
  StructField("age", StringType, false),
  StructField("filledLater", StringType, true)
)
```

Observed Result Schema:

```
StructType(
  StructField("name", StringType, true),
  StructField("age", StringType, false),
  StructField("filledLater", NullType, true)
)
```

This can be solved by using `.map(x => x: ExampleOutput)`, but this is less than desirable. Is there a better solution to automatically update the schema without manually casting the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is impractical to achieve the exact thing what you are looking for, I recommend you either to

1. generate a collection of field name to DataType (spark) mapping e.g. `myTypes:Map[String, StructType]` and you can simply cast to that type -

```
inputDS
  .withColumn("filledLater", lit(null).cast(myTypes("filledLater")))
```

In this way you don't have to use Dataset[T], rather use Dataframe

Or

2. Use some reflection API like "[shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422945/how-to-get-map-of-field-names-to-field-types-of-case-class-with-shapeless)" to use similar casting as mentioned above and use your (configurable) case class..

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using a map in our current solution, wasn’t sure if there was a better solution. I’ll mark this as accepted! Thanks!