# Programmatically generate JSONPath or similiar from a case class

Tags: scala, reflection, shapeless, jsonpath

I'd like to generate all the possible JSONPath from a given case class itself and not an instance of the case class (preferably).

Simple case class with simple nesting:

```
case class Inner(innerA: String, innerB: String, innerC: String)
case class TestCase(a: String, b: String, inner: Inner)
```

For `TestCase`, I'd like to produce (prefer declaration order but not a must):

```
root.a
root.b
root.inner
root.inner.innerA
root.inner.innerB
root.inner.innerC
```

Or something that'll easily transform into valid JSONPath. The purpose for this is so we can define several `case class` in Scala and provide the user with a list of valid JSONPath that they can use to extract information.

Right now, there's no problem doing:

1. `case class` to JSON
2. JSON to `case class`
3. Retrieve a value via JSONPath (as a string) from JSON by using `gatling` (see [here](https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath)) with something like `JsonPath.query(jsonPathString, jsonObj)`

Using `circe` it looks like I can do one step further and do `root.inner.innerA` (see [here](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html)) and get/set the value. However, I couldn't figure out how to produce the list of JSONPath using either `circe` or `gatling` (which feels like doing the reverse of what is being offered by those libraries).

An alternative I can think of is to recursively go through `classOf[TestCase].getDeclaredFields`. Further searching produces:

1. [Scala. Get field names list from case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189754/scala-get-field-names-list-from-case-class)
2. [Scala 2.10 reflection, how do I extract the field values from a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079113/scala-2-10-reflection-how-do-i-extract-the-field-values-from-a-case-class/16079804#16079804)

However, it looks like I still need to recursively go through each field and see if there's anything nested. Is this the best approach?

Samples:

- Instance of case class : `TestCase(a = "alpha", "beta", inner = Inner(innerA = "innerAlpha", innerB = "innerBeta", innerC = "foo"))`
- JSON produced of above: `{"a":"alpha","b":"beta","inner":{"innerA":"innerAlpha","innerB":"innerBeta","innerC":"foo"}}`
- JSONPath evaluator : http://jsonpath.com/ (e.g. `$.inner.innerA`)

Current solution(?):

```
def recursive(members: MemberScope, parent: String): Unit = {
  members.foreach { member =>
    member match {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor =>
        println(s"$parent.${m.name}")
        recursive(m.returnType.members, s"$parent.${m.name}")
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}

recursive(typeOf[TestCase].members, "$")
```

Which produces:

```
$.inner
$.inner.innerC
$.inner.innerB
$.inner.innerA
$.b
$.a
```

EDIT: Supposedly shapeless is able to do this but I haven't quite figured it out.